# Sub-unity bound for the norm of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive semidefinite matrices such that $0 \leq A,B \leq I$ and suppose that $A + B >0$. Does it follow that $\|(I-A)(I-B)\|_2 < 1$?

This is true for the scalar case--let $0\leq a,b\leq 1$ and $a+b = \alpha > 0.$ Then

$(1-a)(1-b) = e^{\log(1-a)(1-b)} = e^{\log(1-a)+\log(1-b)} \leq e^{-a-b} = e^{-\alpha} < 1.$

Unfortunately there's not really a matrix analog to this argument.

I've tried using the typical eigenvalue inequalities and messed around with complex representations using holomorphic functional calculus, but I can't get anything to work so far.

I've also done some computing and the result seems to be true; however, I could just have easily looked over a simple counterexample.

Comment: It definitely holds that the maximum eigenvalue of $(I-A)(I-B)$ is less than $1$, but I doubt that your statement generally holds.

Comment: For a counterexample, I suspect that taking 
$$
A = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad B = b \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$
for some $0<a,b\leq 1$ will do the trick.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your comment. user1551 seems to have a proof. Can you tell me more about why you suspect this form of $A$ and $B$ will give a counterexample?

Comment: Never mind that; user1551's answer is completely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since both $A$ and $B$ are between $0$ and $I$ in positive semidefinite partial ordering, both $\|I-A\|_2$ and $\|I-B\|_2$ are bounded above by $1$. Therefore, for any unit vector $x$, we have
$$
\|(I-A)(I-B)x\|_2\le\|I-A\|_2\|(I-B)x\|_2\le\|I-A\|_2\|(I-B)\|_2\|x\|_2\le1.\tag{1}
$$
If $\|(I-A)(I-B)\|_2=1$, then $\|(I-A)(I-B)x\|_2=1$ for some unit vector $x$. Therefore by $(1)$ we must have $\|(I-B)x\|_2=\|I-B\|_2=1$. Since $I-B$ is positive semidefinite, $\max_{\|u\|_2=1}\|(I-B)u\|_2$ is attained only at unit eigenvectors corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $I-B$. Therefore $(I-B)x=x$, i.e. $Bx=0$. But then the condition $\|(I-A)(I-B)x\|_2=1$ implies that $\|(I-A)x\|_2=1$. Therefore $Ax=0$ too. Hence $(A+B)x=0$, which is a contradiction to the assumption that $A+B>0$.